# Windows version of Steam not running in wine

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I'm sorry if this is and easy fix, (I'm new to Ubuntu) but I've been trying to install the windows version of steam to play Windows only titles. The installation worked fine, but whenever I run the steam executable, nothing loads (not even the text) and I'm left with a blank window that vaguely resembles steam

After idling for a while, an error message pops up reading as follows: http://pastebin.com/v2AvuGCh

If I need to be more specific, tell me.

Thanks in advance to anyone who finds this

Comment: I think your answer is posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/306665/can-i-play-windows-steam-games-on-ubuntu

Comment: thanks for bringing this post to my attention, I looked for posts that might give me an answer to my question. apparently I wasn't thorough enough